# Help with calculating the determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

Does anyone know how to go about answering the following? Any help is appreciated!

1. Calculate the determinant of $D = \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 2 \\
   2 & -1
   \end{bmatrix}$ and use it to find $D^{-1}$.
2. Verify that $I = DD^{-1}=D^{-1}D$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Comment: In addition to what Daniel R said, do you have a textbook?  Why not use it?  Someone will probably downvote your question.  Despite the lack of effort you have shown in this question, I will give some advice: memorizing the formula for the inverse of a 2-by-2 matrix is tricky and you should be able to use Gauss-Jordan elimination instead (which also works for bigger matrices), and choose which method you prefer.

Comment: Megan - If you find an answer to be helpful, we encourage you to *accept* one answer. (Only one answer per question can be *accepted*). To accept an answer, just click on the $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer you want to accept. It turns green when you click on it!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For a $2\times2$ matrix we have 
$$
|\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}|=ad-bc
$$

Use the equality $$A\cdot adj(A)=|A|I$$

Where $adj(A)$ is the [Adjugate matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#2_.C3.97_2_generic_matrix)

Answer (score 0):

for a $2\times2$ matrix D = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix} in general the inverse  is given by the formula 
       $\frac{1}{ad-bc}\times \begin{bmatrix}
d & -b \\
-c & a
\end{bmatrix}$, provided $ad-bc\not =0$. As mentioned above the inverse of a matrix when its $det\not=0$, is given by $A^{-1}$ = $\frac{1}{detA}\times adjA$.